# How to select last child of tspecific class in css

Tags: html, css

Need to apply CSS to div with class name `test` except last div having class `test`.

in below case  - 
first  2 div.test should have margin but 3rd div.test should not.

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="test">
      <div>The first paragraph.</div>
   </div>
   <div class="test">The second paragraph.</div>
   <div class="test">The third paragraph.</div>
   <div class="test">The fourth paragraph.</div>
   <div class="test-1">The firth paragraph</div>
</div>
```

`div.test-1` should not apply anything

Comment: By index of child:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: By last child:https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_last-child.asp

Comment: [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)

Comment: By particular type:https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Comment: nth-child will not work for me, no of elements are flexible. its just need to select last div.test no matter how may div.test are there.
:last-of-type will not work with class(only works with element)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.test:nth-last-child(-n+2)` to select the last child of `.test`

```css
.test:nth-last-child(-n+2){
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="test">
      <div>The first paragraph.</div>
   </div>
   <div class="test">The second paragraph.</div>
   <div class="test">The third paragraph.</div>
   <div class="test">The fourth paragraph.</div>
   <div class="test-1">The fourth paragraph.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To select specific child, you can use nth-child(number) property:

```css
        div:nth-child(2) {
          color:red
        }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="test">
     <div>The first paragraph.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">The second paragraph.</div>
  <div class="test">The third paragraph.</div>
  <div class="test">The fourth paragraph.</div>
  <div class="test-1">The firth paragraph.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

Example using a suggestion from @ לבני מלכה

```css
.parent .test:not(:nth-child(4)) {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="test">
      <div>The first paragraph.</div>
   </div>
   <div class="test">The second paragraph.</div>
   <div class="test">The third paragraph.</div>
   <div class="test">The fourth paragraph.</div>
   <div class="test-1">The firth paragraph.</div>
</div>
```